# Using Azure CDN for Sharepoint assets

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, azure, cdn

I would like to use Azure CDN for my static files located in Images library for example, is this possible, I couldn't find anything how to do this? This is not for the web parts, but just for assets, so I can get CDN link for the assets.

Edit: just to mention, this CDN would be used outside of the Sharepoint. I need a CDN, but if another solution exists that isn't Azure, I'm open to it. Sharepoint CDN unfortunately doesn't allow access from external domains.

Thanks